# Windows 10 Docker error during docker run

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I am trying to run docker container on windows 10
When I run "docker run -it nanoserver cmd" using elevated Windows CMD shell
I am getting the following error

> docker: Error response from daemon: container
> ea592a56c97f4f2e80ab76e5b7615b4caa5d8a64bc3c704092d243d9b444487a
> encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: winapi error # 3489661596 (0xd000029c).

Comment: What's your set-up? Are you using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) on Windows 10 pro? Or are you using docker-machine to run Virtualbox nodes. Have you set-up according to [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/deployment_nano)?

Comment: I am using windows 10 Enterprise build version 1607 (OS Build 14393.82)

Comment: Yes i am using windows 10 Enterprise edition Version 1607. I am have following these instruction "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10"

Comment: I did follow instruction you have post but i am getting following error when i try to run Install-PackageProvider command                         install-packageprovider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NanoServerPackage'.
The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the
tags.

Comment: So you're running the container but it's giving you an error inside the container? btw the command should be `docker run -it microsoft/nanoserver cmd`

Comment: it is not even starting container I get these error when I try to run container